# Does this alternating series converge or diverge $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \frac{n + \cos(n)}{n + \cos(\cos(n))}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to figure out whether this series converges or diverges but I am not sure which test to use as I always get a super messy formula. Am I missing something obvious that tells me if it converges or not ?.

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{n}\,
\frac{n + \cos\left(n\right)}{n + \cos\left(\cos\left(n\right)\right)}
$$

Comment: **Hint:** Do the terms approach zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|(-1)^n\frac{n+\cos n}{n+\cos(\cos n)}\right|=1,$$your series diverges.

Comment: Thanks! Why does that prove it diverges?

Comment: @user520403 Nth term test.

Comment: @user520403 Because when a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: @user520403 A series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff the sequence of partial sums, $b_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i$ converge.  In particular this would imply that for each $\epsilon>0$ one has some $N$ for which $|b_m-b_n|<\epsilon$ for each $m,n>N$.  This in turn implies that $|b_{n+1}-b_n|<\epsilon$, i.e. that $|a_n|<\epsilon$, which in turn implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.  By contrapositive then, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$ (*either because it converges to something else or doesn't converge at all*) this implies $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.